# What can I consider as an ansatz metric for a static but not spherically symmetric solution?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry, coordinate-systems

I already am aware that any static metric can be written in the form of
$$g_{\alpha\beta}= -N^2(x_1,x_2,x_3)dt^2+g_{ij}(x_1,x_2,x_3)dx^idx^j.$$ I am also aware that for a constant time slice one can use something like a gaussian normal coordinate system to breakdown this into the form of $$g_{ij}= dn^2+g_{ab}(x_a,x_b)dx^adx^b.$$ But I am pretty sure that Gaussian normal coordinate systems are local and a near horizon approximation.
Is there some other way I can write my matrix as "$g_{ij}= d\rho^2+g_{ab}(x_a,x_b)dx^adx^b$" where $\rho$ is some radial coordinate.